# Spring Batch Performance Improvement

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am writing a Spring Batch which needs to read from a Database table and then process the read data (while reading more database tables) and then finally write to a database. The performance of the Spring Batch needs to be updated so that 10 files are written every 1 second.

I followed this [post](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/scalability.html) and managed to increase some performance by using multi threaded steps.

But still the desired performance goal can not be met. Can anyone guide me on how to get more throughput from Spring batch.

Comment: Is the performance goal realistic or just made up...

Comment: @Deinum This is an actual performance goal set by client

Comment: Nice that it is set but is it realistic? I you reed millions of rows this might be unrealistic...

Comment: @Deinum Yes, I felt that their expectation is a bit too much. But I should try before saying no.

Comment: In regards to both the comments above and the answer provided so far, what is the bottle neck right now?  Is it the inserts?  Is it the reading?  You can only effectively tune what you know...

Comment: I gave some ideas for performance improvements on another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32717610/performance-optimization-for-processing-of-115-million-records-for-inserting-int. Perhaps it will give you a couple of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your performance depends of a lot of factors.

For example :

- What does your query looks like? Are there any joins/subrequest who could slow down your whole job?
- What does your processor do?
- Did you use indexed tables (with a specific index tablespaces on a faster drive)?

Parallel processing, multi-threading and partitionning is only a small part of your performance gain.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have to improve on Database access and see.