# Will Spring Batch prevent my program from grinding to a halt on 94 million transactions if the Garbage Collection is an issue?

Tags: spring-boot, mariadb, spring-batch

This may look like a similar question to [Performance optimization for processing of 115 million records for inserting into Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32717610/performance-optimization-for-processing-of-115-million-records-for-inserting-int) but I feel it's a different problem, and the other question does not have a definitive answer because of some lack of clarity.

I am loading a netCDF file consisting of the following variables and dimensions into three tables in a database to collect data from multiple data-sources

```
Variables:
Time: 365 entries in hours since Jan 1, 1900
Latitude: 360 entries, center of 1/2 degree latitude bands
Longitude: 720 entries, center of 1/2 degree longitude bands
Precipitation: 3 Dimensional Array Time, Lat, Lon in dimensions
```

The three tables I am constructing are like so:

```
UpdateLog:
uid    year    updateTime

Location:
lid    lat    lon

(hidden MtM table) UpdateLog_Location:
uid    lid

Precipitation:
pid    lid    uid    month    day    amount
```

If you do the math, the Location (and hidden table) will have around 250k entries each for this one file (it's just the year 2017) and the Precipitation table will have up to 94 million entries.

Right now, I am just using Spring Boot, trying to read in the data and update the tables starting with Location.

When I have a batch size of 1, the database started off updating fairly quickly, but over time bogged down. I didn't have any sort of profiling set up at the time, so I wasn't sure why.

When I set it to 500, I started noticing clearly the steps as it slowed down each update, but it started off much faster than the batch size of 1.

I set it to 250,000 and it updated the first 250,000 entries in about 3 minutes, when on a batch size of 1, 72 hours wouldn't even come close. However, I started profiling the program and I noticed something. This seems to be a problem not with the database (35-40 seconds is all it took to commit all those entries), but with Java, as it seems the Garbage Collection isn't keeping up with all the old POJOs.

Now, I have been looking at 2 possible solutions to this problem. Spring Batch, and just a direct CSV import to MariaDB. I'd prefer to do the former if possible to keep things unified if possible. However, I've noticed that Spring Batch also has me create POJOs for each of the items.

**Will Spring Batch remedy this problem for me? Can I fix this with a thread manager and multi-threading the operation so I can have multiple GCs running at once? Or should I just do the direct CSV file import to MariaDB?**

The problem is that even if I can get this one file done in a few days, we are building a database of historical weather of all types. There will be many more files to import, and I want to set up a workable framework we can use for each of them. There's even 116 more years of data for this one data source!

Edit: Adding some metrics from the run last night that support my belief that the problem is the garbage collection.

```
194880 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
1165541217 nanoseconds spent preparing 518405 JDBC statements;
60891115221 nanoseconds spent executing 518403 JDBC statements;
2167044053 nanoseconds spent executing 2 JDBC batches;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
6042527312343 nanoseconds spent executing 259203 flushes (flushing a total of 2301027603 entities and 4602055206 collections);
5673283917906 nanoseconds spent executing 259202 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 2300518401 entities and 2300518401 collections)
```

As you can see, it is spending 2 orders of magnitude longer flushing memory than actually doing the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to thank those who assisted me as I have found several answers to my question and I will outline them here.

The problem stemmed from the fact that Hibernate ends up creating 1,000 garbage collection jobs per POJO and is not a very good system for batch processing. Any good remedy for large batches will avoid using Hibernate altogether.

The first method of doing so that I found utilizes Spring Boot without Hibernate. By creating my own bulk save method in my repository interface, I was able to bind it to a SQL insert query directly without needing a POJO or using hibernate to create the query. Here is an example of how to do that:

```
@Query(value = "insert ignore into location (latitude, longitude) values(:latitude, :longitude)",
       nativeQuery = true)
public void bulkSave(@Param("latitude") float latitude, @Param("longitude") float longitude);
```

Doing this greatly reduced the garbage collection overhead allowing the process to run without slowing down at all over time. However, for my purposes, while an order of magnitude faster, this was still far too slow for my purposes, taking 3 days for 94 million lines.

Another method shown to me was to use Spring Batch to bulk send the queries, instead of sending them one at a time. Due to my unusual data-source, it was not a flat file, I had to handle the data and feed it into a ItemReader one entry at a time to make it appear that it was coming from a file directly. This also improved speed, but I found a much faster method before I tried this.

The fastest method I found was to write the tables I wanted out to a CSV file, then compress and then transmit the resulting file to the database where it could be decompressed and imported into the database directly. This can be done for the above table with the following SQL command:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE `location.csv`IGNORE
INTO TABLE Location
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY `,`
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'  
LINES TERMINATED BY `\n`
(latitude, longitude)
SET id = NULL;
```

This process took 15 minutes to load the file in, 5 minutes to compress the 2.2 Gbs of files, 5 minutes to decompress the files, and 2-3 minutes to create the files. Transmission of the file will depend on your network capabilities. At 30 minutes plus network transfer time, this was by far the fastest method of importing the large amounts of data I needed into the database, though it may require more work on your part depending on your situation.

So there are the 3 possible solutions to this problem that I discovered. The first uses the same framework and allows easy understanding and implementation of the solution. The second uses an extension of the framework and allows for larger transfers in the same period. The final one is by far the fastest and is useful if the amount of data is egregious, but requires work on your part to build the software to do so.

Answer (score 1):

4 tables?  I would make 1 table with 4 columns, *even if* the original data were not that way:

```
dt DATETIME  -- y/m/d:h 
lat SMALLINT
lng SMALLINT
amount ...
PRIMARY KEY (dt, lat, lng)
```

And, I would probably do all the work directly in SQL.

1. `LOAD DATA INFILE` into whatever matches the file(s).
2. Run some SQL statements to convert to the schema above.
3. Add any desired secondary indexes to the above table.

(In one application, I converted hours into a `MEDIUMINT`, which is only 3 bytes.  I needed that type of column in far more than 94M rows across several tables.)

At best, your `lid` would be a 3-byte `MEDIUMINT` with two 2-bytes `SMALLINTs` behind it.  The added complexity probably outweighs a mere 94MB savings.

Total size:  about 5GB.  Not bad.

Comment: I appreciate your response, but part of the approach I am using is to try to work through the Spring Framework here as some of the organizations we are contracting for have started to push it. As for the number of tables, it's desired that we can drop any one of the datasets without having to affect any of the other tables, which is why I am working with 4 tables, not just a single table here.

Comment: @ChthonicOne - Condolences.  I find that most 3rd party packages just get in the way.  Since this is a "one-time" process (or monthly), can't you argue to use skip Spring?

Comment: @ChthonicOne - Find, keep 4 tables; sounds like even less pre-processing would be needed?

Comment: The problem right now isn't the preprocessing. I ran some analytics last night and added them to the question. Admittedly this was only for the location table and it's 259,200 records. 1 minute 4 seconds to do everything JDBC related, 3 hours 15 minutes spent flushing used POJOs from memory. The problem is clear, the Garbage Collection isn't keeping up with the work.

Comment: As for the argument that we could skip Spring for this, that is on the table. This is more for a proof of concept though, and so that someone here learns how to use Spring well enough that we can convince this organization that they can't always do all the work on their own using Spring. The idea is I'm to try to do everything I can through Spring to see what it's limitations are, so we can provide good arguments for our services.

Comment: @ChthonicOne - "POJO"?  (I know nothing about Spring, in spite of responding to 59 Spring-MySQL questions.)  I would expect virtually any MySQL query against 259K rows to be under 10 seconds.  (Though it may take some optimizations to get the time down to that.)  Suggestion:  Do the equivalent analytics in SQL; if it comes back orders of magnitude faster than 3:16:04, you have your case made.

Comment: @ChthonicOne - And keep in mind that database engines (eg, MySQL), are designed to efficiently handle millions, even billions, of rows in optimal ways.  Spring probably is not.  Even _just_ fetching of the raw data into the client _may_ be slower than having the server do all the work!  (An occasional Question is "Should I use SQL to summarize the data, or pull all the data into my client and do it there?"  Almost always the answer is "Let MySQL do the SUMs, GROUP BYs, ORDER BYs, etc.")

Comment: A POJO is a "plain old java object" and is how the JPA, or "Java Persistance Architecture,"  represents a row in a database table. The problem here is that the system is creating 259k java objects to post to the database, and doing it in the normal time, but the Garbage collection once those objects aren't needed anymore is taking forever. In other words, the query is being executed in a normal time frame, but the overhead from the JPA is at fault, and it shouldn't be. There is no reason for the GC to be running this slow.

Comment: @ChthonicOne - `<cynical>`That feeds into my feeling that 3rd party packages in front of MySQL tend to be useful only for 'toy' projects and prototyping; for anything larger, they are likely to get in the way of performance and scaling.`</cynical>`

Comment: That may be true, but the GC is a Java issue, and this must be one that they have run into before. If so they likely have a way through their system to improve performance despite the GC issue. This is what I am looking for in a solution here.

Answer (score 1):

> I've noticed that Spring Batch also has me create POJOs for each of the items.

Spring Batch does *not* force you to parse data and map it POJOs. You can use the [PassThroughLineMapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/mapping/PassThroughLineMapper.html) and process items in their raw format (even in binary if you want).

I would recommend to use partitioning in your use case.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this. I will have to look into the PassThroughLineMapper then. None of the tutorials I read mentioned it so far.

Comment: If you mean MySQL's `PARTITIONs`, please elaborate.  I don't see any advantage.

Comment: No, I mean Spring Batch partitioning feature: the input dataset is divided into partitions where each partition is processed by a separate thread in parallel.